# Why can't I knitting the R markdown to PDF?

Tags: r, pdf, knitr

When I try to knit to PDF I have this error:
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:。 not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

l.387 explained by ``gdp''。

Try running pandoc with --latex-engine=xelatex.
pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Execution halted

I did includes all files in the working directory but still don't know why.

Comment: maybe some help in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/inputenc-error-unicode-char-u8-error-while-trying-to-write-a-degree-symbol)

Answer (score 1):

I could not comment on the previous post by scoa, but the YAML header argument misses a space and should read:

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once. Try installing Pandoc on your machine, reboot and try again. You can download Pandoc [here](http://pandoc.org/installing).

Also, you'd most likely need to install MiKTeX.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am not sure that is the problem : the error did not say that pandoc wasn't found, but that it produced an error when running.

Answer (score 0):

This is an encoding error. The easiest way to deal with it is to add the following line in the YAML preamble of your document.

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine:xelatex
---
```

Comment: Should be "latex_engine" instead of "latex-engine".